# How do I get my program to check if a icon exists on the page

Tags: java, html, css, jsoup, selector

I am trying to create a program that looks for the bullhorn icon on the page so I can run that through an if statement. The page I'm looking at is https://www.yelp.com/biz/sabor-unido-newark. Using the inspector tool on Chrome, I found the html for the bullhorn icon:

```html
<span aria-hidden="true" style="fill: #ea5c1d; width: 30px; height: 30px;" class="icon icon--30-bullhorn icon--size-30">
    <svg class="icon_svg">
        <use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="#30x30_bullhorn"></use>
    </svg>
</span>
```

I am using JSoup, and have been struggling to find the correct method that will achieve this. Basically I want it to say, "If the page has the bullhorn icon, then do this." I've tried numerous Element selectors and the `hasAttr()` method, but none seem to work. This very well might be because I'm not very fluent in HTML, and maybe am getting the selector syntax wrong. Regardless, what do you think?

Here's the current iteration of what I'm working with:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Attribute;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class BullHorn
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, Exception, RuntimeException
    {        
        String linkUrl = "https://www.yelp.com/biz/mega-pizza-newark?osq=pizza";

        Document linkClick = Jsoup.connect(linkUrl).timeout(3000).get();

        boolean bullhorn;

        for(Element element : linkClick.getAllElements())
        {
            for(Attribute attribute : element.attributes())
            {
                if (attribute.getValue().equalsIgnoreCase("#30x30_bullhorn"))
                {
                    bullhorn = true;
                }
            }
        }

        if (bullhorn = true)
        {
            System.out.println("True");
        }

        else 
        {
            System.out.println("False");
        }
    }
}
```

The thing is, this always returns true, even on links that don't actually have the bullhorn icon.

Comment: Thank you for including your code : )

Comment: You have a really big syntax error in `if(bullhorn = true)`, remember that `=`'s is the assignment operator and `==`'s checks for equality between primitives. You could also write the if statement as `if(bullhorn)`.

Comment: wow over 2 hours of constantly trying to do different things, and it was a missing ='s. That's funny. Thanks.

Comment: Yea that will happen, the important thing is that you didn't give up. Have a look at my answer, it addresses another *problem* in your code.

Answer (score 1):

You have a syntax error in `if(bullhorn = true)`, remember that `=`'s is the assignment operator and `==`'s checks for equality between primitives. You could also write the if statement as `if(bullhorn)`.

**On a side note, but still important:**

You should `break` out of the for loops if you have found the bullhorn, there's no need to continue iterating through each element.

For instance:

```
public class BullHorn {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, Exception, RuntimeException {        
        String linkUrl = "https://www.yelp.com/biz/mega-pizza-newark?osq=pizza";

        Document linkClick = Jsoup.connect(linkUrl).timeout(3000).get();

        boolean bullhorn;

        for(Element element : linkClick.getAllElements()) {
            for(Attribute attribute : element.attributes()) {
                if (attribute.getValue().equalsIgnoreCase("#30x30_bullhorn")) {
                    bullhorn = true;
                    // no need to continue looping, we've found bullhorn
                    break;
                }
            }

            // no need to continue looping, we've found bullhorn
            if(bullhorn == true) {
                break;
            }
        }

        if (bullhorn == true) {
            System.out.println("True");
        } else {
            System.out.println("False");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Makes sense, I'm still pretty new to Java, and didn't really know about breaks. Now that I know, this will be pretty useful in the future.